# How to manage semi-static configuration in Blazor WASM deployments

Tags: blazor-webassembly, blazor-pwa

I built a blazor WASM app which I want to publish as a docker image, but in a way that it is someone configurable for consumers of the image. The API endpoints it talks to should be configurable, as well as some colors and icons.

The default .NET way of configuring applications is through `AppSettings.json`, so I explored that route.
The best solution I was able to find, is to map an external `AppSettings.json` file into the docker container which is started, which then contains custom configuration.

I noticed that besides `AppSettings.json`, after my build there is also a `AppSettings.json.br` and `AppSettings.json.gz` file, which given their extension, I presume are compressed versions of the original file.

Also, the app is configured as a PWA app, and is built using AOT. I noticed if I only replace `AppSettings.json` and leave the compressed versions in place (with their original content), the installed PWA app seems to revert back to the default settings every now and then.

This leaves me with the following process of publishing a customizable docker image:

1. Publish application using `dotnet publish ...`
2. In my `Dockerfile`, copy published files on top op nginx docker image
3. In same `Dockerfile`, remove `AppSettings.json.br` and `AppSettings.json.gz` files
4. Publish docker image with instructions to mount external `AppSettings.json` file to customize the application

But it feels wrong to delete files our of the set of published files the dotnet SDK produces. Am I missing something? How are other people doing this?